# Concatenar hierarquia

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```php
<?php
function obterID($string) {
    $res = preg_match('~id="([\w]+)"~i', $string, $IDs);
    if ($res){
        return $IDs[1];
    } else {
        return "";
    }      
} 

// Lê conteúdo do txt
$documento = '<ul id="titulo1" class="titulo">
   <li>
      <p>TÍTULO I</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo1" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 1º...</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo2" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 2º ....</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo3" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 3º ....:</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo4" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 4º ....:</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="titulo2" class="titulo">
   <li>
      <p>TÍTULO II</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="capitulo1" class="capitulo">
   <li>
      <p>CAPÍTULO I</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo5" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 5º ....:</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="capitulo2" class="capitulo">
   <li>
      <p>CAPÍTULO II</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo6" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 6º ...</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo7" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 7º ...</p>
   </li>

</ul>
<ul id="artigo8" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 8º....:</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo9" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 9º É as.</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo10" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 10. ....</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo11" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 11. ....</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="capitulo3" class="capitulo">
   <li>
      <p>CAPÍTULO III</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul id="artigo12" class="artigo">
   <li>
      <p>Art. 12. São brasileiros:</p>
   </li>
</ul>';

$linhas = explode("<ul", $documento);

$novalinhas = "";
$concatenaTitulo = "";

foreach ($linhas as $novalinha){


$novoTituloSlug = ObterID($novalinha);
if (empty($novoTituloSlug))
    continue;

$concatenaTitulo .= $novoTituloSlug;  
}

echo $concatenaTitulo;
?>
```

### [**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/JgLnwR)

Gostaria de concatenar por hierarquia, como num *breadcrumb* (mas, não sei como fazer um *breadcrumb*).

Este é o resultado que gostaria em cada `foreach`:

```all
titulo1
titulo1artigo1
titulo1artigo2
titulo1artigo3
titulo2
titulo2capitulo1
titulo2capitulo1artigo5
titulo2capitulo2
titulo2capitulo7artigo6
```

Mas ele só concatena, sem substituir:

```all
titulo1
titulo1artigo1
titulo1artigo1artigo2
titulo1artigo1artigo2artigo3
```

E vai até:

```all
titulo1artigo1artigo2artigo3artigo4titulo2capitulo1artigo5capitulo2artigo6artigo7artigo8artigo9artigo10artigo11capitulo3artigo12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode filtrar essas informações pela classe (*titulo*, *artigo* ou *capitulo*) e colocá-las num [*array associativo*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Utilize a função abaixo no lugar da função `obterID`:

```php
function retornarInfo($texto, $classe) {
    $expressao = '~id="([\w]+)" class="'. $classe .'"~i';
    $casamento = preg_match($expressao, $texto, $resultado);
    return (($casamento == 1 ? $resultado[1] : ""));      
}
```

Para criar a hierarquia, utilize a função abaixo:

```php
function criarHierarquia($linhas){
    $informacoes = [];
    $indiceTitulo = $indiceCapitulo = "";
    foreach ($linhas as $linha){
        $titulo   = retornarInfo($linha, "titulo");
        $capitulo = retornarInfo($linha, "capitulo");
        $artigo   = retornarInfo($linha, "artigo");

        if (!empty($titulo))
            $indiceTitulo = $titulo;
        if (!empty($capitulo)){
            $indiceCapitulo = $capitulo;
        } elseif (!empty($artigo)){
            if (!empty($indiceCapitulo))
                $informacoes["titulo"][$indiceTitulo]["artigo"][$indiceCapitulo][] = $artigo;
            else
                $informacoes["titulo"][$indiceTitulo]["artigo"][] = $artigo;
        }
    }
    return $informacoes;
}
```

### Exemplo de utilização:

```php
$linhas = explode("<ul", $documento);
$informacoes = criarHierarquia($linhas);
```

Percorra a array `informacoes` do seguinte modo:

```php
foreach ($informacoes as $info){
    foreach ($info as $titulo => $artigos){
        echo "{$titulo}<br>";
        foreach ($artigos as $artigo){
            foreach ($artigo as $capitulo => $subArtigo){
                if (is_array($subArtigo)){
                    foreach($subArtigo as $capArtigo){
                        echo "{$titulo}{$capitulo}{$capArtigo}<br>";
                    }                   
                } else {
                    echo "{$titulo}{$subArtigo}<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para exibir a hierarquia da *array* faça:

```php
echo "<pre>", print_r($informacoes, 1), "<pre>";
```

### - [**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/ZQhVCX)

Comment: Mas assim, não concatenou, desde jeito 
`titulo1`  `titulo1artigo1`  `titulo1artigo2` `titulo2` `titulo2capitulo1` `titulo2capitulo1artigo5`

Comment: Acredito que sim, pois são uls com lis dentro dele

Comment: Sim, pois, eu vejo que as leis não passam de ul com ul dentro dele. Então gostaria de estrutura-los assim, você tem outra visão sobre a estrutura?

Comment: É cara, depois olha a página oficial da constituição, arranjei para minha cabeça, kkkk. Pois a estrutura varia muito, e eu quero fazer com as outras leis que também variam demais. kkkk, mas se puder, depois olha a constituição e me diga, que formatação é aquela, não sou fera, mas, me parece muito zoada, e se você tiver alguma sugestão para hierarquizar corretamente, eu agradeço, kkk

Comment: @AlêMoraes bah, Mas a hierarquia do exemplo está correta? A página que você diz é [*essa*](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/decreto-lei/Del4657.htm)? Eu não estou conseguindo entender como criar essa hierarquia que você quer. =/

Comment: A hierarquia é essa mesmo, por exemplo, o título 1, só tem 4 artigos, não tem mais nada, já o título 2 tem 5 capítulo e dentro dos capitulos tem alguns artigos, outro exemplo, no título 3, capítulo 5, existem duas seções com alguns artigos dentro

Comment: @AlêMoraes Veja [**essa imagem**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbd7C.png), com base no HTML postado na pergunta essa hierarquia está correta?

Comment: Pelo que vi da sua imagem, acho que não teriam as duas primeiras linhas, pois, pelo que entendi, parece que o titulo 1 e o titulo 2 estão dentro de titulo.

Comment: @AlêMoraes Editei a resposta.

Comment: Nossa man, funcionou, uauuuuu. Vou estudar seu código para entender seu raciocínio, merece todos os votos!!!